# ¿Cómo puedo crear un fichero dentro de un directorio almacenado en una variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script

¿Como creo un fichero directamente dentro de un directorio si está almacenado en una variable? ¿O se tendría que crear y luego mover?

Intento que se guarde con el siguiente comando:

```
echo $(touch $dir/$file)
```

pero no se guarda.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo: ¿tienes una variable que contiene una cadena del tipo "directorio/fichero", es decir tanto la ruta como el nombre del fichero?

Comment: según se desprende de la sintaxis `$dir` es la carpeta y `$file` es el archivo `$()` lanza una nueva shell, `touch` crea un archivo

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¿te dirigías a mí? En tal caso, utiliza [`@fedorqui`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83) para que me llegue la notificación. Suponiendo que te referías a mí, mi duda persiste: el redactado de la pregunta no coincide con lo que dice luego el código. Además, no hay ninguna necesidad de utilizar una nueva shell para esto.

Answer (score 1):

yo lo haria así:

```
mkdir $direccion; touch $direccion/$archivo
```

Comment: Hola Dani, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal que la editases para añadir algo más de información (qué es lo que hace el código, por qué funciona, etc). Lee [answer] para más información. Un saludo.

Comment: en realidad no hay mucho que explicar =P, yo agregaría el modificador `-p` al `mkdir`por si `$direccion` contiene subcarpetas onda `echo $(mkdir -p $DIR; touch $DIR/$FILE)` siendo `DIR=app/cache`crea ambos niveles